# RUBY+ PRAWN -Template::Error (can't convert nil into Float)

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I'm using PRAWN to create pdf.
I'm getting error on this line:

```
pdf.text story.description.gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, ""), :size =>12
```

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: please provide more code and a complete trace